# Ethereum Wallet 0.5.2 >Confirm Encryption Loss> message when extracting zipped folder

Tags: mist, homestead, installation, windows, encryption

Trying to download Ethereum Wallet 0.5.2 mist off github and I after 
downloading I click through folders and get the following message:

[image: Confirm Encyption Loss]

This occurs when I attempt to extract the compressed folders. I have read that this may be due to the originator compressing folders on a mac and extractor is using a PC but I really have no idea and I assume encryption is of paramount importance.

Can someone please let me know what is occurring and how I can go about resolving this issue and safely update to homestead and keep my crypto secure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research and all the information I can find is due to a bug in how Windows handles zip files created on a Mac as well. The initial files most likely had their [NTFS encryption set](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457065.aspx) which throws this error when you attempt to unzip it.

I also found [this answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/beb4a086-bc9b-4b04-99e5-5edf1f43ae84/disable-efs-prompt-confirm-encryption-loss-when-copying-files-from-local-drive-to-network-drive?forum=w7itprosecurity) about the same issue:

> Encrypted files might need to be decrypted before the files can be copied or moved to volumes that are not EFS-capable. For any file operation in My Computer, if the destination volume is not capable of re-encrypting the file, you will receive the error message notifying encryption losing.
>
> As a work around, you can use copy and xcopy command-line parameters to enable copying of encrypted files to non-EFS capable volumes.
>
> Copy encrypted files to non-EFS capable volumes by using the copy command:  copy /d
>
> Copy encrypted files to non-EFS capable volumes by using the xcopy command: xcopy /g

It does seem like, besides the annoying prompt, there is no real issue or problem ignoring the prompt and continuing on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, tayvano! If it were you, would you just unzip it unencrypted or would you follow the command line protocol?

Comment: I would unzip it and continue on. The program itself has no reason to be encrypted. If something goes wrong and the program fails to launch or something, I might try the Command line way.